# How to Access Class in Web Project through BL that exist in DAL

Tags: oop, asp.net-identity

I have 3 layers in my project

```
1) DAL
2) BL
3) Web
```

Web only has an access to BL, where BL has an access to DAL. I have ASP.NET Identity Model Class `ApplicationUser` in DAL. In my Web project, there is a class `Startup.auth.cs` that need an access to this class. I would like to access this through BL, how it could be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your entire application lies in the same namespace. Now, you can create a reference of your class in DAL and use it in a particular method of the DAL. Now invoke this method in BL by creating the reference of DAL.

Answer (score 0):

`Startup.Auth.cs` is not part of the business logic in any way - it is implementation detail of how the web-site knows about authentication. So BL should not know about this class. I advise refactor your classes so that BL does not need to dip into `Startup.Auth`, otherwise you'll get a big ball of spaghetti.

Comment: So, what changes I need to make? As I mentioned my ApplicationUser class inside DAL, how can I access it in Startup.auth.cs? Do I need to keep ApplicationUser class inside Web project?

Comment: My startup.auth.cs sit inside web project, I want to access ApplicationUser class that currently reside inside DAL.

Comment: oh, in this case I don't see anything wrong with referencing DAL in your web-project.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing right now. But what If I don't want to reference DAL in my Web? I only want to keep reference BL in Web and wondering if some how though BL I can access ApplicationUser inside Web. Is it possible?

Comment: no, not possible. You want to access something that you explicitly do not allow to access - not logical.

Comment: Hmm, Only for this class I have to keep reference of DAL. Any suggestion you can provide. I think, you get an idea how my app structuraized and what I want to achieve.

Comment: no suggestions other than already given. Another suggestion is not to separate your solution into these classes if your project is relatively small. Every time I've done 3-projected solution, I regretted it and had to put various hacks to go around the limitations. So now for smallish applications I put everything into one project.